# How To Structure a Swing Application

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I don't really have much experience with swing, or GUI design in general for that matter (a few WPF applications in university is about the height of it), however I have been tasked with refactoring part of a swing legacy application at work.

The part I've been asked to refactor revolves around a popup window which can display in three different formats depending on a certain value object. These 3 different formats all share a few base fields, and then have additional ones determined conditionally. The class responsible for this GUI element is ~5k long and I was thinking it should be split into three subclasses, with the shared stuff in base class which they all extend. However I have absolutely no idea if this is the correct approach or not.

Could anyone highlight some strategies used in dealing with different swing components which share elements such as buttons/fields etc?

Additionally, are there any large OSS swing applications which can be used to learn from?

More info: The application I am working on is a large legacy application which is rather horrifically structured at the moment. I'm new to the team (and a fairly recent grad so don't have much experience in this area) and have been asked to try and break down one of the huge classes which is responsible for the display of this popup at the moment into smaller more maintainable components. Essentially there is a pop up in the application which allows the user to respond to certain events, and this has three different appearances depending on the sub type of the request they need to respond to. A large portion of the GUI elements are consistent across all three sub types, as such I am interested to know if inheritance would be the best approach here or are there other strategies for dealing with this?

Comment: "*The part I've been asked to refactor revolves around a popup window which can display in three different formats depending on a certain value object*" can't you use `event.getSource()` ?

Comment: This is a great question, but tough to answer in a few paragraphs.  Generally. break up your GUI into however many JPanels are necessary to define the GUI, and create a Java class for each JPanel.  Use composition when defining Swing components.  Use inheritance only if you're overriding a method in the JComponent.

Comment: @joey Sorry if I'm coming across like an utter moron - use it how? At the moment the large class takes a parameter p, and depending on the subtype of this parameter certain view elements are added to the panel. About 50% of the elements are always displayed irregardless of the parameter passed. My initial thought was to leave the common fields in the main class, then have three sub classes to house the type specific stuff. But this could be an horrid idea for all I know!

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc thanks for the reply, I have started to break everything into smaller panel based classes. As always I'm trying to favor composition over inheritance where possible, however have you any advice for dealing with shared components? I.e. panels which share components like buttons or text fields but have certain additional fields as well?

Comment: @OhButYouWillPets can you update a question a bit?What you want to do?What is your main goal?What kind of application is this?

Comment: @OhButYouWillPets If you are upto sharing, please be alot of careful about [concurrency in swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: @OhButYouWillPets: I don't understand what you mean by "panels which share components".  Panel A contains Button A, and Panel B contains Button B, even if the user of the GUI thinks they are the same button.  All GUI components are independent of each other, even if they have the same ActionListener.

Comment: At the moment literally everything is in the one class, so if I wanted to have the buttons with the same functionality I'd have to replicate the code across Panel A and Panel B? Would you advise creating Button A in Panel A, Button B in Panel B and then have them share an action from elsewhere?

Comment: @OhButYouWillPets Even with the same functionality, make different buttons for each Panel, or form.If you dont know much about swing, first learn it, things will become clear.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Reading the comments, I think I can answer this question.  A true answer would require a book.

1. Break up your GUI into as many nested `JPanel`s as it takes to describe your GUI.  A simple nested `JPanel` that uses a `BorderLayout` is preferable to a complicated `JPanel` that uses a `GridBagLayout`.  To be clear, I'm not criticizing a `GridBagLayout`.  It's useful when creating a form.  But it's not the only Swing layout manager.
2. Put each nested `JPanel` into its own class.
3. Use composition when using Swing components.  Use inheritance if and only if your class will override one of the `JComponent` methods.
4. Each `JPanel` has its own `JButton`, `JLabel`, etc. components.  `JBUtton` A is defined for `JPanel` A, and `JButton` B is defined for `JPanel` B, even if the user of the GUI thinks they are the same button.  You can minimize the duplication by creating a GUI model that contains the text of the labels and buttons.  You must eliminate the duplication of action code (the code that's executed when the button is pressed) by writing common `ActionListener`s that `JButton` A and `JButton` B can execute.
5. A Swing application **must** start with a call to `SwingUtilities.invokelater()`.  This ensures that the Swing components are defined and used on the Event Dispatch thread (EDT).
6. Only **one** `JFrame` is used in a Swing application.
7. Each JPanel **must** have a Swing layout manager defined.
8. Certain components, like `JList` and `JTable`, work better when enclosed in a `JScrollPane`.

I'm sure I've forgotten a few things, but this should be a good start.

Comment: Thanks a million for this Gilbert, it's a great starting point for me.

Comment: Really good answer! What name would you recommend for the one and only JFRame?

Comment: Something with Gui, Main, Frame and/or the name of the project if it is Gui-heavy. Be sure to have a project-intern name convention.

Answer (score 2):

What if you were to set up an abstract class that creates the 50% shared code, and then extend from that?

For example:

```
abstract class BasePopupPanel extends JPanel {

    public void initialize() {
        // Initialize all the shared code here.
        // eg. add(new JButton("TEST");
    }
}
```

And now you create the actual popup panels:

```
public class GiraffePopupPanel extends BasePopupPanel {

    public void initialize() {
        super.initialize();
        // Here you do all the initializations for this class.
    }
}
```

You can create as many of these as you would like. When it comes time to add them...

...let's say you have a method that is called `displayPopup`, then the signature would look like this:

```
public void displayPopup(BasePopupPanel popup) {
    // do stuff regarding JDialogs, etc.
    // ...
    popup.initialize();
    // do more stuff...
}
```

I hope that gives you one view on how you could refactor your classes.