# Working with local image or audio files in Swing applications?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, intellij-idea

I'm working on a small Swing game, for which I'm designing custom JButton icons and sound effects myself. I'm using IntelliJ and I want to know what is the simplest, most efficient way of referencing those files. As in, where should I put my source files in my project structure and how should I "import" them in my code as say, an ImageIcon. Alternatively, is there an IntelliJ feature making the process faster? I looked up other threads and it was either very specific to the OP's project structure, or very convoluted for something as simple as using a custom image. I already know how to use a file from the Internet, but not local files.

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I don't understand your question but if you look for Swing project management you can look at [How To Structure a Swing Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565599/how-to-structure-a-swing-application).

If you are using `JButton(String text, Icon icon)` constructor (`Icon` is interface that is implemented by `ImageIcon`), and `ImageIcon(String filename)` constructor for `ImageIcon` I will suggest creating something like at [Using Swing Components: Examples](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/) or just study it.

And next you can create:

```
Icon a = new ImageIcon("images/a.jpg");
JButton button = new JButton("Something in button", a);
```

Comment: Loading images by file reference won't work once the app. is in a Jar (e.g. for deployment). See my comment above.